# Send commands in expect script only after certain text appears on screen

Tags: linux, expect

I am writing an expect script that will interact with a program meant to download log files from website. It goes like:

```
Expect 
spawn program link
send "\n"
send "\n
```

This will start downloading the file.

But the file is long and download time varies (depending on the speed of the internet), so I cannot specify timeout or sleep directly. 
But after the file is downloaded the text [OK] appears.
The output after file download is 
[OK] Download complete

---

So I want to make script with expect so that once a file is downloaded and text [OK] appears on screen it will further send another command to quit or exit and start another download.

I have tried using:

```
Spawn program 
Expect "OK" or expect "\[OK]" 
Send command
```

But it did not work.

How can I do this?

Comment: just `expect -timeout -1 -ex "\[OK]"`

Comment: It did not worked. After download is complete and [OK] appears, quit command is not sended l.

Comment: please paste your real script or a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

## !/bin/expect

spawn program url_to_log_file
send "\n" #This will send enter
send "\n" #This will send enter
after above two send file downloading will start. At end of download it will show
Name of file

### [OK] Download complete

send q #This will exit the program

So question is how can i use expect to wait till downloading completes and then send q to exit. 
I have used  expect "[OK]" send q but it does not quit even after download is complete